# Are the DocuSign C# SDK methods thread safe?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I currently have thousands of envelopes and I need to automate pulling them down and storing their form data in a database. The thing is getting the envelopes (about 22000 of them) and calling ListStatusChange() for each iteratively takes a really long time. So I thought I could use TPL's Parallel.ForEach to do that concurrently. When I do this, I get an error that the remote service closed the connection.

So, are the methods in the SDK thread-safe? Does anyone have a better way to handle this other than what I have explained I am trying to do?

So far, I have tried the iterative process, but it is taking more than an hour just to get the envelopes and their form data.

I have tried the TPL library, but I am getting network errors. I am assuming DocuSign is closing the connection since the calls are coming in rapidly from the same app.

I thought I could do something similar to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-foreach-loop-with-partition-local-variables

I expected the calls to be made concurrently to speed up the process, but instead I got an exception that the remote server closed the connection.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits

Comment: A lot of APIs throttle connections, to prevent abuse. If you post some code, maybe we can pinpoint a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting the hourly API limit which is 1000 API calls per hour and it will reset on the next hour. The error message is misleading and we'll look to see why you didn't get the correct error. The latest version of the C# SDK is thread-safe. If you are using an older version - please upgrade to latest.
You will need to limit the number of API calls you make per hour to 1000. 
To check the actual error you can look for API logs in DocuSign

Comment: Ok, this is going to be tricky. Let's say I have 4000 envelopes. I make a call to get the envelopes. Then for each envelope, I have to make a call to get the form data. How will that not reach a 1000 call limit? In addition, if I used an iterative method, I do not get any issues even though I am making more than 1000 calls per hour.

Comment: is this a one-time task? you can request a one-time exception of the hourly limit. If this is an ongoing activity, might have to take longer than 4 hours...

Comment: you need to contact your support or sales person in DocuSign to request to increase your API limit